# How to parse a two dimensional JSON array in java

Tags: java, arrays, json

This is my json data

```
 {
    "tag1":["haaai ","hello"],

    "tag2":[["haai1","haai2"],["hello1","hello2","hello3"]]
 }
```

I can successfully read array `tag1` using my java code

```
 JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("tag1");    
 Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();

 while (iterator.hasNext()) {    
        String text = iterator.next();    
        System.out.println(text);
 }
```

But, I can't read the `tag2` array using the above method. Any idea?

Comment: You have two seperate objects in your json; you have to retreive them seperately. Or re-think your json data structure, i.e. with a root object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't read using the same method because the format is different.
 You will have to use 2 loops instead.

```
 JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("tag2");    
 Iterator<JSONArray> iterator = msg.iterator();

 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Iterator<String> innerIterator = iterator.next().iterator();
        while (innerIterator.hasNext()) {
             String text = innerIterator.next();    
             System.out.println(text);
        }
 }
```

Comment: its working fine. thanks for your valuable comments.